# How to post jsonstring as RESTFULL request to postman

Tags: java, database, spring, rest, web-services

I have a class like the following:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class MyTestClass {
@JsonProperty("first")
private List<String> first = new ArrayList<>();
@JsonProperty("second")
private List<String> second = new ArrayList<>();
@JsonProperty("third")
private List<String> third = new ArrayList<>();

public static MyTestClass emptyFilter() {
    return new MyTestClass();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unused") //JSR311
@Nonnull
public static MyTestClass fromString(@Nullable String jsonString) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(jsonString)){
        return emptyFilter();
    }
    return JsonUtils.fromJSONString(jsonString, MyTestClass.class, false);
}
```

}

My question is about the input of a *RESTfull call webservice*. My request must have a `filter` parameter which is supposed to refer to this class. So, what I give as the filter parameter is like the following:

```
{"MyTestClass":{"first":[],"second":[],"third":[]}}
```

But I always get this error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'MyTestClass'
```

I am new to Spring framework and my questions may be stupid ones:

1. I know that the filter parameter should be a `jsonObject` that includes three `JsonArray`s. What should be the name of the main parameter inside the `jsonObject` which includes the `JsonArray`s. I have used the class name, as you can see. Is that correct? If I have understood it correctly from some other questions on `stackoverflow`, that is what I should use when I use a class which is written based on `Spring`.
2. If it is not correct, how can I find what that should be called? I can see the names of the `jsonArray`s simply by looking at the class, because they are the variables of the class. But what about the name of the `jsonObject` which include all these arrays?
3. From the class, it seems to me that the class must also accepts empty strings as the filter. But I have also tried with that and it doesn't work. Where should I look for the problem?

I should also mention that my work is in a company and it's a small part of a very big project which has recently been converted to Spring framework and we are testing if everything is again working.

Comment: what library is JsonUtils. I dont see an import for it

Answer (score 1):

The root element does not need to be referred by a name in the json. The test string should be

```
{"first":[],"second":[],"third":[]}
```

Comment: He has them that's what @Data from lombok, does. It's completely not clear to me what his asking but let's see if you got it right.

Comment: @Monish Thanks a lot for your answer. I have also tried your format and I got the same error. Where else can the problem be, then?

Comment: @user1419243 perhaps if you can share the calling code, maybe it will be clearer

Comment: @MonishSen You mean the request I send to postman? That's here:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyProject/search/profiles/?searchstring="test"&offset=0&limit=10&filter={"first":[],"second":[],"third":[]}

Comment: @user1419243 this is not the calling code. The class that invokes MyTestClass.fromString() . I suspect the problem is there

Comment: @MonishSen Thanks for your patient answers to my stupid questions :)
As I said, I'm not the author of the code. I just searched the method in the whole workspace and there is no reference! Is that the problem or that can be that the fromString method is not necessarily called as a normal java method and it can be probable that it's called in some other way (like a Restfull call or something like that)?

Comment: search for uses of `MyTestClass` there is no reason to call `fromString` it looks more like a test method to me. @user1419243

Comment: @user1419243 Also what is the stacktrace of `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'MyTestClass'` this error?

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem. The design had been changed by some other person and I just had to use the content of the filter as separate parameters. No need to have jsonObject as the input. Thanks anyway :)